# How do i execute this function only if screen is bigger than

Tags: javascript

I want to execute this function only when screen is bigger than 1000px.

```
window.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    event => {
      const nav = document.querySelector('.module')
      if (250 <= window.scrollY) {
        nav.classList.add('flyin')
        nav.classList.remove('module')
      }
      else nav.classList.List.add('none')
    },
    false
)
```

Comment: You can check for the width with `window.innerWidth` inside the function and proceed only if the width fulfills your requirements.

Comment: -Lukasz how do i do that

Comment: `var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth, jQuery(window).width() || 0); if (width > 1000) { /* CODE HERE */  }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
  window.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    event => {
      const nav = document.querySelector('.module')
      if (250 <= window.scrollY) {
        nav.classList.add('flyin')
        nav.classList.remove('module')
      }
      else nav.classList.List.add('none')
    },
    false
 ) 
}
```

Comment: why do `var w` when the variable name is not descriptive and it's only used once?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method resize in the addEventListener